# If $A \subseteq B$, does $\mbox{dist}(x,\partial A) \le \mbox{dist}(x, \partial B)$ hold for all $x \in A$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with euclidean metric. Furthermore let
$$
\mbox{dist}(X, Y) := \inf\{|x - y| : x \in X, y \in Y\}.
$$
Does the following implication hold?

> $A \subseteq B \implies \forall x \in A: \mbox{dist}(x,\partial A) \le \mbox{dist}(x, \partial B)$

Problems could arrise if one of the boundaries $\partial A$, $\partial B$ is empty. But in this case $A$ or $B$ would be clopen, and hence equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\emptyset$. I think I am better off assuming $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \mathbb{R}^n$ to avoid problems.

---

Thanks to a suggestion by **GEdgar** I came up with the following proof:

Let $s \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the straight line with $s(0) = x \in A$ and $s(1) = y \in \partial B$. I want to show, there exists $t' \in [0,1]$ with $s(t') \in \partial A$.

It is safe to assume $x \not \in \partial A$, since then $\mbox{dist}(x,\partial A) = 0$ and the inequality holds trivially. Same goes for the assumption $y \not \in \partial A$.

Consider now the function
$$
f(x) := (1-2 \chi_A(x)) \cdot \mbox{dist}(x,\partial A).
$$
One can check that this function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$:

- No problems on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \partial A$, since as a property of metric spaces $\mbox{dist}(\cdot,\partial A)$ is continuous and furthermore $(1-2 \chi_A(x))$ is constant.
- Let $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x \in \partial A$. Then 
  $$
  |(1-2 \chi_A(x_n)) \cdot \mbox{dist}(x_n,\partial A)|
  \leq \mbox{dist}(x_n,\partial A) \to 0 = \mbox{dist}(x,\partial A),
  $$
  since the closedness of $\partial A$ implies $\mbox{dist}(x,\partial A) = 0$ iff $x \in \partial A$.

Now the claim follows by application of the intermediate value theorem.

**Is this proof correct?**

**Does the claim also hold for more general metric spaces $(X,d)$ which are only connected/path connected?** Of course the definition of $\mbox{dist}$ would be modified accordingly $(| x - y | \to d(x,y))$

Comment: Show this: the line segment from your point $x$ in $A$ to a point of $\partial B$ passes through a point of $\partial A$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks. I have added a solution based on your suggestion in my post. I would appreciate it, if you could take a look.

Comment: Note that $A ≠ ∅$ doesn't imply $∂B ≠ ∅$.

Comment: It is false for a general connected metric space. Let $X$ be the unit circle on $\mathbb{C}$ with one point deleted, parametrized by $\gamma(\theta) = \exp(i\theta)$, $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$. Take $A$ = $\gamma((0,\pi])$, and $B = \gamma((0,3\pi/2])$. Then the boundaries are $\{-1\}$ and $\{-i\}$ respectively, and you can easily find a point in $A$ that's closer to $-i$ than to $-1$.

Comment: @QiyuWen: Yes, this is basically what user87690 suggested in his answer (see below).

Answer (score 2):

For the general case, consider $X = \{e^{iφ}: φ ∈ [0, 2π - ε]\}$, $A := \{e^{iφ}: φ ∈ [0, π]\}$, $B := \{e^{iφ}: φ ∈ [0, 2π - 2ε]\}$. Topologically, $X$ is just a closed interval, and hence a metrizable compact path-connected space.

Comment: I dont understand. Why do you consider a section of the circle (I assume this is $X$)?

Comment: Consider $x = 1 ∈ A$. What is $∂A$? What is $∂B$?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. $\partial A = A$ and $\partial B = B$ and the claim doesn't hold. So there is no generalization of the claim?

Comment: That's not right, $∂A$ is not $A$, $∂B$ is not $B$ (that would be the case for $X = ℝ^2$). Actually, the claim would hold if it was.

Comment: $\partial A = \{-1\}$ and $\partial B = \{e^{i(2\pi - 2 \varepsilon)}\}$. But how do I proceed only knowing that $X$ is metrizable.

Comment: @el_tenedor: Well, strictly speaking, I haven't defined the metric, but I meant $X$ as a subspace of the complex plane, i.e. $ℝ^2$.

Comment: I forgot about the fact, that $(X,d)$ with the induced metric will do the job... Crucial point is probably, that $X$ is not a convex subset, correct?

Comment: Yes, the convexity is used in the idea of GEdgar.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=d(x. \partial A)$, then the open ball $B_r(x) \subset intA$ for otherwise $B_r(x)=(int A \cap B_r(x)) \cup (int A^c \cap B_r(x))$ which violates the connectivity of $B_r(x)$. The above enquality is justfied because $B_r(x)$ is an open ball so $\partial A$ doesn't intersect $B_r(x)$, otherwise $d(x, \partial A)<r$.

Therefore $\forall y \in A^c$, $d(x,y)>d(x,\partial A)$. Since $\partial A$ is the set of limit point of $A^c$ and the distance function is continuous, one can show $d(x,\partial A) \le inf\{d(x,y):y \in A^c\}$, hence we have

$$d(x,\partial A)=\inf\{d(x,y): y \in A^c \} \le \inf\{d(x,y): y \in B^c\} = d(x,\partial B)$$

Comment: How do you prove the equalities?

Comment: $B^c \subset A^c$, so there are more candidates in $A^c$, this means the infimum is smaller.

Comment: I was asking about the equalities, not the inequality.

Comment: Because $\partial A$ is the limit point of $A^c$ and distance function is continuous.

Comment: Oh sorry I was wrong.

Comment: @user87690, I've corrected my post.

Comment: @student Note, that $int (A) \cup int (A^c) \neq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @student I like your idea, but I don't think the proof is yet correct/complete: You still haven't proved the equalities, only thing we know so far is, that $d(x, \partial A) \leq \inf\{d(x,y) \colon y \in A^c\}$.

Comment: What if $\operatorname{int}(A) = ∅$?

Comment: @user87690 In that case $d(x,\partial A) = 0$, so the inequality holds whatever $d(x,\partial B)$ is.

Comment: @el_tenedor, the equality holds because $\partial A$ is the set of limit points of $A^c$. Note for any $y \in \partial A$, we can always find $y_k \in A^c$ such that $y_k \rightarrow y$ and thus $d(x,y_k) \rightarrow d(x,y)$.

Comment: @student Let $y_k \to y \in \partial A^c$ with $y_k \in A^c$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $d(x,y_k) > d(x, \partial A)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies $d(x,y) = \lim_{k \to \infty} d(x,y_k) \geq d(x,\partial A)$. This proves $d(x,\partial A) \leq \inf\{d(x,y): y \in A^c \}$.

Comment: @el_tenedor, just choose $z_k \in \partial A$ with $d(x, z_k) \rightarrow d(x, \partial A). $Then choose $y_k \in A^c$ accordingly such that $d(y_k,z_k)<1/k$. Then $d(x,y_k) \rightarrow d(x,\partial A)$.

Comment: @student. I'm sorry, the proof I provided in my previous comment lead to a wrong conclusion. Yours is better but still doesn't prove equality (and with no additional there won't be, as the counterexample provided by user87690 shows). All your comment does is prove the following: $d(x,y_k) \to d(x,\partial A)$ implies $\inf\{d(x,y) \colon y \in A^c\} \leq lim_{n \to \infty} d(x,y_k) = d(x,\partial A)$. Furthermore, you still haven't fixed the fact that $B_r(x)=(int A \cap B_r(x)) \cup (int A^c \cap B_r(x))$ is wrong since $int A \cup int A^c$ doesn't exhaust $\mathbb{R}^n$.See my first comment.

Comment: @el_tenedor, because $B_r(x)$ is an open ball so  $\partial A$ doesn't intersect $B_r(x)$, otherwise $d(x, \partial A)>r$. My comment proved one-sided inequality, and the other side is in my post.

Comment: To make my answer more clear, I have updated my post and filled the gap.